# Newtonsoft.Json исключение при пустом объекте

Tags: c#, json

Падает с ошибкой:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type.

Часть json: `{"arr":{}}`

Часть класса для десерилизации:

```
public Arr[] arrshopitem_categories { get; set; }

public class Arr
{
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: должно, но не передается. в этом то и ошибка. в обычных ситуациях передается массив и все работает, но иногда приходит это и возникает исключение

Comment: а коментарием мне к ответу не можете написать?

Comment: напишите в вопросе данные когда объект не пустой, что бы было понятно с чем идёт работа, и код и модель для распарсанья, у вас в вопросе маловато сведений, для полноценного ответа

Answer (score 4):

Смотрите тут у вас массив `Arr[]`

А тут `{"arr":{}}` объект.

Получается несовпадение, отсюда и ошибка.

Должен быть и там и там массив, или и там и там объект.

Для правильного чтения должно передаваться что-то типа

```
[{"name": "hallow"}]
```

или в пустом варианте

```
[]
```

Либо вам надо изменить логику, модель распарсивания, но что бы это написать в ответ не хватает информации в вопросе.